# Read column data with dask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I have column data, which is currently read using  `numpy.loadtxt(filename,usecols=[0,1,2,3],dtype=float)`. This works fine when the file size is not so large. At the moment, the data file is about 50GB, and the `numpy.loadtxt()` takes too long.
Is there a more efficient way to read this data using `dask` and subsequently convert it to a numpy array?

PS: I have not used dask before.

Comment: Even if you use dask, you may encounter memory error or slow loading process but, it depends on your memory size. You may use chunksize then convert it to numpy array.

Comment: @Bugs_Bunny I am doing this on a machine with 64GB RAM, which I guess is sufficient. My concern is if, by using dask, I can save a significant time.